# printf - implementation in C

Tags: c

This may be a silly question, but... I tried to implement `printf`, but for some reason the output I get is not exactly what I expected. any idea what it could be? I would appreciate some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdarg.h> 

static int print(const char *restrict fmt, ...);
static int getfloat(float *);
static char *itoa(int, char *, int);
static void _strrev(char *);


int
main(void)
{
    float i1 = 0.0, i2 = 0.0, noi1 = 0.0, noi2 = 0.0, res = 0.0;

    print("weight - item 1: ");
    getfloat(&i1);

    print("no. of item 1: ");
    getfloat(&noi1);

    print("weight - item 2: ");
    getfloat(&i2);

    print("no. of item 2: ");
    getfloat(&noi2);

    res = ((i1 * noi1) + (i2 * noi2)) / (noi1 + noi2);
    print("%f\n", res);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


static int
print(const char *restrict fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    char buf[BUFSIZ] = {0}, tmp[20] = {0};
    char *str_arg;
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    va_start(ap, fmt);

    while (fmt[i] != '\0') {

        if (fmt[i] == '%') {
            i++;
            switch (fmt[i]) {
                case 'c':
                    buf[j] = (char)va_arg(ap, int);
                    j++;
                    break;

                case 'd':
                    itoa(va_arg(ap, int), tmp, 10);
                    strcpy(&buf[j], tmp);
                    j += strlen(tmp);
                    break;

                case 'f':
                    gcvt(va_arg(ap, double), 10, tmp);
                    strcpy(&buf[j], tmp);
                    j += strlen(tmp);
                    break;

                case 's':
                    str_arg = va_arg(ap, char *);
                    strcpy(&buf[j], str_arg);
                    j += strlen(str_arg);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else { buf[j++ ] = fmt[i]; } 
        ++i;
    }
    fwrite(buf, j, 1, stdout);
    va_end(ap);
    return (j);
}


static int
getfloat(float *p)
{
    int c, sign = 0;
    float pwr = 0.0;


    while (c = getc(stdin), c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
        ;   /* ignore white spaces */
    
    sign = 1;   /* record sign */
    if (c == '+' || c == '-') {
        sign = (c == '+') ? 1 : -1;
        c = getc(stdin);
    }


    for (*p = 0.0; isdigit(c); c = getc(stdin))
        *p = 10.0 * *p + c - '0';

    if (c == '.') { c = getc(stdin); }

    for (pwr = 1.0; isdigit(c); c = getc(stdin)) {
        *p = 10.0 * *p + c - '0';
        pwr *= 10.0;
    }
    
    *p *= sign / pwr;
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetc(c, stdout);
    return (float)c;
}


static char *
itoa(int n, char *strout, int base)
{
    int i, sign;

    if ((sign = n) < 0)
        n -= n;

    i = 0;
    do {
        strout[i++] = n % base + '0';
    } while ((n /= base) != 0);

    if (sign < 0) { strout[i++] = '-'; }
    strout[i] = '\0';

    _strrev(strout);
    return (strout);
}


static void
_strrev(char *str)
{
    int i = 0, j = strlen(str) - 1;

    for ( ; i < j; ++i, --j) {
        int tmp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

here is the output I get:
19.44444466

and this is the output that I expect: (or the one that I would at least like to receive, which is the one in itself that I get when I use printf)

```
19.444445
```

Comment: `19.444445` is `19.44444466` rounded. What result do you get if you ask `gcvt()` for 8 digits instead of 10? Or conversely, what result do you get from `printf("%.8f\n", res);`?

Comment: @WeatherVane the result I get when I use: printf("%.8f\n", res); is 19.44444466, now I think I more or less understand. Thank you!

Comment: `tmp[20]` is far too small with `gcvt(-DBL_MAX, 10, tmp);`.  More like `tmp[320]`.  Evan `float` could need maybe 50 `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>    f, F   The double argument is rounded and converted to decimal
>           notation in the style [-]ddd.ddd, where the number of
>           digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the
>           precision specification.  If the precision is missing, it
>           is taken as 6;
> ```

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html

The default precision for `%f` is six so `printf()` is rounding the result to six decimal places.

You'd need to play with the `ndigit` argument to `gcvt()` which is the total number of significant digits (both before and after the decimal point). You are passing in `10` so your answer has two digits before the decimal and eight after for this particular number.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `gcvt()` don't do exactly what `printf()` do, at least with your compiler. Check it with a "real" `printf` with the same value.

Since you didn't gave the numbers you used for the test (avoid `getfloat()` and initialize directly `i1`, `i2`, `noi1` and `noi2` with required constants in your question), I can't run it and tell you why exactly - or if it even happens with my own compiler.

Usually, the source code for `printf` is at least two times bigger than yours, so you may have missed some vicious subcases. If I remember well, `printf` has code to decode an IEEE-754 directly and don't rely on `gcvt`.

Comment: The numbers I used for the test were,
`
weight - article 1: 15
| no. of article 1: 5
| weight - item 2: 25
| no. of article 2: 4
`

and I guess I'll have to dig a bit more about `gcvt()`, thank you very much.